# TIARA - a tool for enhancing SE beauty

Tags: app, api-v2

### About

Quality is an important area of concern for Stack Exchange sites.  Immediate quality concerns are generally handled through a combination of flagging and downvoting.  However, some things don't warrant flags, and locating and purging useless, downvoted content can be tricky, especially when you have a limited supply of 20k users with delete privileges.

TIARA (Technical Innaccuracies and Altogether wRong Answers, named for a flag dismissal reason) is intended to help both moderators and users identify worthless content, and handle it efficiently.  It generates a list of old, consistently downvoted posts.  In the case of questions, only closed or unanswered questions are shown.

There is a decent amount of disagreement about what should be done about downvoted, useless answers.  This is a tool which can be employed to find them, and attempts to help people looking at the list choose an action if they think one is required.  This grew out of a discussion on [Gaming Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/on-quality-answers-and-the-task-of-moderators), and a follow up discussion on SE chat ([here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4258777#4258777), and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4260095#4260095)).

#### Usage

To load the application, click [this link](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/maint/).  Pick a site from the drop down, and it will generate a list of potentially problematic content, sorted by lowest score first, and then by age.

There's a bit of help text intended to guide new users as to how to handle things that show up on the list, but the hope is that it helps to focus site maintenance efforts on older, neglected, and downvoted content.

This is still in the early stages, so any feature requests or feedback are welcome.

#### License

BSD 2-clause.  Source code is available from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/agent86ix/stackapps).

### Contact

If you run into bugs, come find me using the chat system.  I am typically in the [StackApps](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps) room, among others.

Comment: Why show only closed questions? Downvoted questions might need closing, whereas I don't know why downvoted closed questions would be different from non-downvoted closed questions.

Comment: I don't see what to do with heavily downvoted answers, really. They're wrong, and clearly shown as such. What needs cleanup isn't the downvoted content really, it's the content that should be downvoted but isn't.

Comment: @Gilles, I added some context to the "About" section, including a controversial meta post and some discussions in SE chat about the topic.  I don't really expect everyone to find this useful, and I'm not attempting to make or set SE policy, just help people (mostly myself) handle what I've been told I should be responsible for.

Comment: Authorization fails for me. “error description: redirect_uri is not under the registered domain for this application”

Comment: @minitech, looks like github changed something - https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io  I'll have to update the domains for all my tools.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @agent86 you might be interested in this https://github.com/PHP-Chat/CVBacklogUI it's what the PHP Chat / [cv-ring], uses to handle bad questions.